# Web Api call with a complex object as parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

My webApi Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ISearchProviderCommandResult ExecuteCommand(ISearchProviderCommand command)
{
  MySearchProvider searchProvider = new MySearchProvider();
  return searchProvider.ExecuteCommand(command);
}
```

My searchCommand object

```
[Serializable]
class SearchProviderCommand : ISearchProviderCommand
{
  public string OperationContext {get; set;}
  public string OperationId{get; set;}
}
```

I have a break point in my webapi controller and a breakpoint on the line 
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

When I try to step into the webapi controller, I get a 500 error and it doesnt even hit the breakpoint inside the webapi controller.  Here are my questions:

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. Can I send complex objects to web api requests?

EDIT:
Based on the asp.net forums and leons directions I changed my WebApi controller to use an object instead of the interface and it works:

```
[HttpPost]
public SearchProviderCommandResult ExecuteCommand(SearchProviderCommand command)
{
  MySearchProvider searchProvider = new MySearchProvider();
  return searchProvider.ExecuteCommand(command);
}
```

Can you tell me how I reconstruct my object from the result?

EDIT: Based leon's suggestion - for those who are interested here is my final caller code

```
public result ExecuteCommand(ISearchProviderCommand searchCommand)
{
  //serialize the object before sending it in
  JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
  string jsonInput = serializer.Serialize(searchCommand);

  HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri(ServiceUrl) };
  StringContent content = new StringContent(jsonInput, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
  var output = httpClient.PostAsync(ServiceUrl, content).Result;

  //deserialize the output of the webapi call
  result c = serializer.Deserialize<result>(output.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

  return c;
 }
}

public class result : ISearchProviderCommandResult
{
  public object Result { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You can pass custom objects as parameters to actions. Depending on the http method you prefix it with an attribute, for post you can use [FromBody].

Comment: i did try that even before I posted the question, sadly that didnt do the trick, should I update my question with the attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a BinaryFormatter? Shouldn't you be encoding your request as JSON since that's what you're sending?

Comment: i found this example online, do you have an example for me to look at?

Comment: I changed my code to serialize this way: `code`var jsonSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        string json = jsonSerializer.Serialize(searchCommand);

        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
        requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);`code`

Comment: On looking at your email again, i've missed what's probably obvious - you're using an interface. I'm not sure you can do that, as WebAPI will attempt to create the object in the parameters, which it can't do on an interface, perhaps you could look at using ModelBinders (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/20/how-to-bind-to-custom-objects-in-action-signatures-in-mvc-webapi.aspx)

Comment: thanks for your answer, please see my edit to my post.  I added a question to the end of it.

Comment: Call .Deserialize(string, type) with the result (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee191864.aspx). You will want to hide all this serialization away in a utility/proxy class which calls out to your service though, so your services see just Interfaces (which you could perhaps accomplish via generic methods).